# How to replace '?' in openjpa query with a real parameters?

Tags: openjpa

Is there any way to get replaced '?' in printed out by openjpa query?

> TRACE openjpa.Query - Executing query: Query: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl@246923;
> TRACE openjpa.jdbc.SQL
>
> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = ? AND ROWNUM <= ?
> [params=(long) 111, (long) 5001]

I verified different combinations with following entries:

> < entry key="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE, Query=TRACE, JDBC=TRACE"/>

and

> < entry key="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true" />

but it seems to be not working, according to expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get replaced '?' in printed out by openjpa query?

I assume you want something like this : `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = 111 AND ROWNUM <= 5001`? If so, no that is not possible. The reason for this is that OpenJPA will always favor setting parameters. Bummer if that isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, this is something what I wanted to know. Thanks !